btcrecover not supporting latest Bitcoin Core wallet format?
Trying to use btcrecover against Bitcoin Core 27.0 wallet.dat file (encrypted with short password) and getting "unrecognized wallet format" error:
The wallet.dat is a valid non-corrupted wallet file, which appears to be in SQL3 Lite format.
$>C:\Python27\python.exe btcrecover.py --tokenlist token.txt --wallet wallet.dat
Starting btcrecover 0.17.10 on Python 2.7.18 32-bit, 16-bit unicodes, 32-bit ints
btcrecover.py: error: unrecognized wallet format; heuristic parser(s) reported:
    WalletPywallet: Unrecognized pywallet format (does not look like ASCII text)
    WalletMultiBitHD: MultiBit HD wallet files must be named mbhd.wallet.aes
    WalletMsigna: Not an mSIGNA wallet: no such table: Keychain
    WalletBlockchain: Can't base64-decode Blockchain wallet: Incorrect padding
    WalletBither: Not a Bither wallet: no such table: addresses, no such table: password_seed

Has anyone faced a problem like this. btcrecover claims to support Bitcoin Core wallet.
https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover

See Who maintains BTCRecover

It looks like btcrecover has not been maintained the past 7 years (the last commit in the repository you link to dates from December 2017). Bitcoin Core introduced a new wallet format (descriptor wallets) in version 0.21 (January 2021), so it seems impossible that this software would support that format.
Descriptor wallets were made the default for new wallets since Bitcoin Core 23.0 (April 2022).
